Could not download junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.1.jar (org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.1)
I am currently having problems building my karate project with gradle. In the console I get this error: “Could not download junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.1.jar (org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.1): Skipped due to earlier error", this error came up when I cloned the repository again, before it worked fine and the only change is the java version.
A part of the build.gradle below:
`repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
implementation group: 'net.masterthought', name: 'cucumber-reporting', version: 1.4.0
testImplementation "com.intuit.karate:karate-junit5:1.4.0"
}`

most likely because your local maven (or gradle) cache is corrupted. please search on the internet on how to delete your local maven repo or gradle cache and try
